Automating a sieve Refilter folder without cron
Every so often a need for some new sieve rules comes along. Along with that are messages in the inbox that would be filtered differently according to the new rules.
The sieve-filter tool makes quick work of refiltering those messages.
What I haven't found a clear recipe for is having an IMAP Refilter folder that collects and runs sieve-filter. Most available solutions use cron in a wasteful manner.
One would need to run external scripts in dovecot that would be triggered on mail being added to the Refilter folder. Ideally such a system would also wait for a bulk move of emails into Refilter to finish before processing the messages to reduce overhead.
Has anybody built all this already?
